# Anyone got references where we can find examples of codes for agent-based simulations of financial markets?

Tags: simulations, models, financial-markets, multi-agent-simulations

I'm looking for references with codes for trying out simple agent-based simulations for modeling financial markets. I mostly worked with MATLAB and R, but I know a bit of python and I am learning C++ slowly... so, ideally, something along those lines would be great.

Again, it doesn't need to be complete, perfect or deal with absurdly complicated cases. I remember having looked at a website from an expert in the field who had some MATLAB codes for just this, but I can't remember what's the website or who wrote it.

EDIT
I just remembered: [Blake Lebaron has just this for some cases](http://people.brandeis.edu/~blebaron/classes/agentfin/Chiarellaetal.html). But if anyone has further readings or references with example codes, I'd be happy to have them.

Comment: Note sure about code examples but Rick Bookstaber's papers on financial crises may help. 2013 NY Times article: https://www.nytimes.com/2013/01/11/business/economy/models-for-financial-risk-are-still-seen-as-flawed.html   2012: https://www.treasury.gov/initiatives/ofr/research/Documents/OFR_Working_Paper_No3_ABM_Bookstaber_Final.pdf  2014: https://www.financialresearch.gov/working-papers/files/OFRwp2014-05_BookstaberPaddrikTivnan_Agent-basedModelforFinancialVulnerability_revised.pdf 2017: http://dx.doi.org/10.1146/annurev-financial-110716-032556

Comment: @Dimitri Vulis I looked through those references. Unfortunately, I am looking for something considerably less verbose and more focused on agent based models. Specifically, I am interested in the nitty gritty details of how they build their models, of how they study them, of how you can fit them to the data and of how these things tend to perform when fitted on data. The verbose frosting on top is not exactly what I need.

Comment: A very simple model is described in chapter 8 of "Numerical Methods and Optimization in Finance" http://enricoschumann.net/NMOF.htm (of which I am a coauthor). The code (MATLAB) is at https://gitlab.com/NMOF/NMOF2-Code/-/blob/master/08_A_gentle_introduction_to_financial_simulation/MATLAB/FXagents.m